# Using a grid row for animateTarget?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I got the impression that `animateTarget` has to be a DOM-element, whichs positon and size will be used as start values for the corresponding animation.

Somehow, when I use `showAt()` on a window and give it the DOM-element of a grid row, nothing happens.

```
oWindow.showAt( 50, 50, oRowDom );
```

I also tried to use a component object

```
oWindow.showAt( 50, 50, oGridComponent );
```

both just let the window appear on the right place but without any animations at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is not possible for a window. **[showAt](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-showAt)** only accepting a boolean or a animantion config for a component as third argument while the window hast a property **[aminationTarget](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-animateTarget)** which will do what you want. But it hast to be a Ext.Element or a ID.

Comment: yeah, I used the property instead of the method argument, which did what I wanted :)